# How do I use a XAML markup extension to convert a DateTime into a string?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a markup extension to convert a DateTime into a string

```
public class DateTimeConverterExtension : IMarkupExtension<string> {
    public DateTime Source { get; set; }
    public string ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        var delta = DateTime.Now -Source;
        if (delta.TotalDays > 0) {
            return string.Format(StringResources.DaysAgo, delta.TotalDays);
        }
        if (delta.TotalHours > 0) {
            return string.Format(StringResources.HoursAgo, delta.TotalHours);
        }
        if (delta.TotalMinutes > 0) {
            return string.Format(StringResources.MinutesAgo, delta.TotalMinutes);
        }
        return string.Format(StringResources.MinutesAgo, 0);
    }

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return (this as IMarkupExtension<string>).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

But when I use this in XAML:

```
<Label Text="{markupExtensions:DateTimeConverter Source={Binding Time}}" />
```

I get the following error:

> No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Source", or mismatching type between value and property.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: this sounds like it should be a ValueConverter

Comment: You are correct, thank you. This fixed my problem. I still wonder why my example doesn't work though.

Comment: Perhaps failed when InitializeComponent was called in constructor, BEFORE BindingContext was set. MarkupExtension ran, but could not find a valid Source. In contrast, a ValueConverter is PART of a Binding expression; it won't be invoked until there is a BindingContext. I think the only Bindings you will see with Markups, are those to `x:Static` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Datetime with Converter.

To work with Converter, **you need to create a class that implements the IValueConverter interface**

**code like:**

```
public class DatetimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var datetime = (DateTime)value;
        //put your custom formatting here
        return datetime.ToLocalTime().ToString("g");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}
```

**then use it in xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <local:DatetimeToStringConverter x:Key="cnvDateTimeConverter"></local:DatetimeToStringConverter>
</ResourceDictionary>
...
<Label Text="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"></Label>
```